# Memory management error in linked list c++

Tags: c++, memory-management, linked-list

I want to know why am i getting an error when i delete temp in this function.

`

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
//NODE FOR LINKED LIST
class node {
public:
    int data;
    node* next;
    node(int val) {
        data = val;
        next = NULL;
    }
    ~node() {
        delete next;
    }
};
//Linked List
class LinkedList {
    node* head;
public:
    LinkedList() {
        head = NULL;
    }
    //checking if head is Null or not
    void insertAtEnd(int val) {
        if (head == NULL) {
            head = new node(val);
            return;
        }

        node* temp = head;
        while (temp->next != NULL)
            temp = temp->next;
        temp->next = new node(val);
        //delete temp;
        //Now if i use this delete temp my loop in display function breaks and runs indefinitely
    }
    void display() {
        cout << "Your List : ";
        node* temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL) {
            cout << temp->data << ">";
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
        delete temp;
    }
};

int main() {

    LinkedList obj;
    //sample tests
    obj.insertAtEnd(10);
    obj.insertAtEnd(20);
    obj.insertAtEnd(30);
    obj.insertAtEnd(40);

    obj.display();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

`

I tried commenting this delete out and it worked but its been leaking memory a simple solution i thought was to make a *temp in constructor then deleteing it in destruction assigning NULL in every function that needs it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand the ownership of the pointers in your code:

- each node is owned by it's predecessor
- except for the head node, which is owned by the `LinkedList` itself

`temp`, however, is never used as a pointer with ownership, so deleting it is conceptionally wrong (in `insertAtEnd` as well as in `display`). Technically explained, in your loop, `temp` will point to the predecessor of the last node added, which is still part of the list. When you now delete `temp`, it's predecessor's `next` pointer will still point to the node you just deleted.

To avoid the memory leak, you need to add a destructor to `LinkedList` and delete `head`. That will destruct the whole chain recursively.

This solution would work, but is stil not ideal, since now `node` will delete something it did not construct, hence the memory management is asymmmetric. Better remove the `delete` operation from the node`s destructor and let` LinkedList` do the creation as well as the deletion.

Answer (score 1):

Your `LinkedList` class should handle the deletion of `nodes`. Generally, you should strive to encapsulate the management of memory in the owner of the data structure, in this case, the `LinkedList` class owns the `node` class. The `node` class does not explicitly allocate any memory, and thus shouldn't handle the deletion of anything.

Your `LinkedList` destructor should look something like this:

```
~LinkedList() {
        node* deleter_node = nullptr; //pointer to current node (node we want to delete)
        deleter_node = head; //deleter points to the head of your list

        while (deleter_node != nullptr) { //traverse list and delete nodes
            node* temp = nullptr;
            temp = deleter_node -> next; //temp ensures we 
                                         //don't loose the pointer to the next node

            delete deleter_node; //delete current node
            deleter_node = temp; 
        }
}
```

To make ownership more explicit, consider rewriting `LinkedList` with the `node` structure as a public member.

Something like this:

```
class LinkedList {
    Node* head;
public:
    struct Node { //node is now a public member struct
        int data = 0;
        Node* next = nullptr;
    };

    LinkedList() { //default constructor
        head = nullptr;
    }
    ~LinkedList() { //destructor handles memory management
        Node* deleter_node = nullptr;
        deleter_node = head;
        while (deleter_node != nullptr) {
            Node* temp = nullptr;
            temp = deleter_node -> next;
            delete deleter_node;
            deleter_node = temp;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Addendum: `LinkedList` would benefit greatly by observing the [Rule of Three (and friends)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). As it stands, copying a `LinkedList` deliberately or accidentally will break the program.

Comment: Side note: You can get rid of `deleter_node ` and just use `head`.  After the destructor finishes, no one can safely use the `LinkedList` again, so preserving the value of `head` isn't important.

Comment: @user4581301 agreed. A real class managing its own memory should include the proper `constructor` and `operator` overloading necessary.